# Problem running latex from FastCGI

Tags: latex, system, fastcgi

I have a program which does a system call:

```
latex somefile.latex
```

This runs ok, when I type it directly in the command line, or when i invoke the program via CGI. But when it is using FastCGI, the system call returns:

```
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.1415926-1.40.10 (TeX Live 2009)
---! Must increase the hyph_size
(Fatal format file error; I'm stymied)
```

I already tried to increase the hyph_size but still no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, now i got it.

it was because my web server was not forwarding the PATH env variable.

closed.